# How to generate the estimate parameters (Standard deviation and mean) for an exponential distribution in r?

Tags: r

For example:

```
#Using QQ-plots to decide which of the Normal, Gumbel and Exponential distribution best fits Qc
qqplot(x=qexp(ppoints(length(data$Qc))), y=data$Qc, main="Exponential Q-Q Plot",
       xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab= "Data Quantiles")
qqplot(x=qnorm(ppoints(length(data$Qc))), y=data$Qc, main="Normal Q-Q Plot",
       xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab= "Data Quantiles")
qqplot(x=qgumbel(ppoints(length(data$Qc))), y=data$Qc, main="Gumbel Q-Q Plot",
       xlab="Theoretical Quantiles", ylab= "Data Quantiles"
```

How can I generate the estimate parameters (ie the standard deviation and the mean) for normal distribution or the exponential distribution after suppose that I think a normal/exponential distribution is a good model to fit my variable?

Answer (score 1):

### exponential

```r
MASS::fitdistr(Qc, dexp, start = list(rate = 0.1))
## 0.0338
## however, the maximum likelihood estimate of the exponential rate parameter
##  is just 1/mean(x):
(r <- 1/mean(Qc))
## 0.0338
pexp(30, rate = r, lower.tail = FALSE)  ## 0.362
```

### normal

The sample mean and sample standard deviation give good estimates of the mean and SD parameters of the Normal (although we *could* use `fitdistr` if we really want to):

```r
MASS::fitdistr(Qc, dnorm, start = list(mean = 25, sd = 7))
pnorm(30, mean = mean(Qc), sd = sd(Qc), lower.tail = FALSE)  ## 0.473
```

### Gumbel

```r
library(fitdistrplus)
library(VGAM)
fitdist(Qc, "gumbel", start = list(location = 25, scale = 1)) 
pgumbel(30, location = 27.03, scale = 7.56, lower.tail = FALSE) ## 0.491
```

### empirical

We could just compute the *observed* probability of values > 30:

```r
mean(Qc>30)  ## 0.469
```

Comment: Hi Dr Bolker, thanks for the help. What is the (mean = 25, sd = 7) in the normal part that you have written, where did you get the values from? What does that mean. Also I ran your commands for the normal part in r and it works. But there are two values that I am unsure how to interpret. https://imgur.com/oywe03S. What are the values in brackets mean?

Comment: Also Dr Bolker, I am thinking about computing the inverse of the probability. Like suppose I am interested in what value of Qc would be exceeded with 95% chance? How would I able to do that?

Comment: (1) you usually have to provide some starting values for the parameters. As long as they on the right order of magnitude it usually doesn't matter what you pick. (2) The parenthesized quantities are the standard errors of the parameter estimates. (3) Use the `q*` function (e.g. `qnorm`).